# How to create another image path using Android Studio Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to create my RegisterFarm Activity which looks like this [image]

My problem is that when using the upload file for both certificate and image of the farm it overwrites one another. I want to create another storage reference where it creates a certificate.jpg. I am unsure of how to add another upload.

My Current Code:

```
    public class RegisterFarm extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText farmname, hectares;
    Button upload_title, upload_pic, submit;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_farm);

    farmname = findViewById(R.id.input_farm_name);
    hectares = findViewById(R.id.input_farm_hectares);
    upload_title = findViewById(R.id.upload_btn1);
    upload_pic = findViewById(R.id.upload_btn2);
    submit = findViewById(R.id.upload_submit);


    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();





    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Farmname = farmname.getText().toString();
            String Hectares = hectares.getText().toString();
            Map<String,Object> farms = new HashMap<>();
            farms.put("Farm Name", Farmname);
            farms.put("Hectares", Hectares);

            fStore.collection("Farms")
                    .add(farms)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterFarm.this, "Farm Registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterFarm.this, "Upload Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    upload_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //open gallery
            Intent opengallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(opengallery,1000);
        }
    });

    upload_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //open gallery
            Intent opengallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(opengallery,1000);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @androidx.annotation.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1000){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            //profilepic.setImageURI(imageUri);

            uploadImagetoFirebase(imageUri);
        }
    }
}

private void uploadImagetoFirebase(Uri imageUri) {
    //upload Image to Firebase
    StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("Farms/" +fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/farm.jpg");
    fileRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterFarm.this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterFarm.this, "Image Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. Its just that I want to be able to create another image stored in firebase without overwriting them since I have two upload button.

Comment: Have you tried to use different uids?

Answer (score 0):

You're uploading the image to this location on Cloud Storage:

```
storageReference.child("Farms/" +fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/farm.jpg");
```

Since you always name the file `farm.jpg`, you just end up with the last image that you uploaded for that user.

If you want to store multiple images for a user, you'll have to generate some unique path for each file they upload. For example, you could add the current timestamp to the file name:

```
storageReference.child("Farms/" +fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/farm_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
```